# Prevent any methods from DI class from being called

Tags: c#, methods, service, dependency-injection, boolean-logic

I currently have a class called Maker that has lots of method calls in it that are being used by several other classes called Doers via Dependency Injection. The Doer classes inherit from MasterDoer.

I have a need to configure the Doer classes to only execute these Maker.Method() calls when a flag is set to True in MasterDoer, and when they meet certain conditions within the specific Doer class.

I can achieve this via if-then statements, but that means either modifying all of my Doer classes, or all of my maker methods. I'm trying to find a cheaper way of achieving this.

This might be code smell, but since it's a multi-threaded Service, it is fairly encapsulated. Any ideas?

**Parent Class**

```
abstract class MasterDoer : IDo
{
    private bool _disableMake = true;

    private List<string> _ignoreList = new { "a", "b", "c"}

    public IMaker Maker { get; set; }

    protected abstract Task DoStuff(object x);
}
```

**Derived Classes**

```
class Doer1 : MasterDoer
{
    protected override async Task DoStuff(object x)
    {
        //prevent call if _disableMake = true && _ignoreList.Contains(x.toString)
        await Maker.Method1(); 
    }
}

class Doer2 : MasterDoer
{
    protected override async Task DoStuff(object x)
    {
        //prevent call if _disableMake = true && _ignoreList.Contains(x.toString)
        await Maker.Method2(); 
    }
}
```

**Injected Class**

```
public class Maker : IMake
{
    //lots of methods
    public async Task Method1();
    public async Task Method2();
    public async Task Method3();
    public async Task Method4();
    public async Task Method5();
    public async Task Method6();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about implementing the methods within the base class? *(Creating a 'proxy')*

**PSEUDO**

```
abstract class MasterDoer : IDo
{
    private bool _disableMake = true;

    private List<string> _ignoreList = new { "a", "b", "c"}

    public IMaker Maker { get; set; }

    protected abstract Task DoStuff(object x);

    public async Task Method1(object x)
    {
        if(disableMake = true && _ignoreList.Contains(x.toString))
            return;

        await Maker.Method1();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

---

```
class Doer1 : MasterDoer
{
    protected override async Task DoStuff(object x)
    { 
        await base.Method1(x); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant for a small amount of methods. Still requires housing the Maker methods within the Doer base, which will be confusing for maintainability. It meets my needs for encapsulation, but feels too much like a pass-through. It also still requires that I code my boolean logic in every method. If 100 of these require a change, I have to update each one individually. However, the conditions will be the same every method, so I could pull it out into a separate wrapper. While this solution works, not quite hitting the nail on the head yet, but I really appreciate it. Thank you.